# Why do I have to URI.encode even safe characters for Net::HTTP requests?

Tags: ruby, http, url-encoding

I was trying to send a GET request to Twitter (user ID replaced for privacy reasons) using Net::HTTP:

```
url = URI.parse("http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?user_id=12345")
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
```

this throws an exception in Net::HTTP:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTP:0x59f5c04>
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1470:in`initialize'

just by coincidence, I stumbled upon a similar code snippet, which used `URI.encode` prior to `URI.parse`, so I copied that and tried again:

```
url = URI.parse(URI.encode("http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?user_id=12345"))
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
```

now it works fine, but why? There are no reserved characters that need escaping in the URL I mentioned, so why do I have to call `URI.encode` for `get_response` to succeed?

Comment: I try your first code and it's works for me

Comment: Your first code snippet works peacefully in Ruby 1.9.1 at least.

Comment: Could you include your environment (Ruby version & OS)? Your initial code works for me as well.

Comment: that's odd. I ran this code in a Rails 2.3.4 app, Ruby 1.8.7 (on MacOS X, Leopard). Does Rails patch the Net::HTTP stuff?

Comment: I've also had no problems running your first example in Ruby 1.8.6 (111).

Comment: okay, thanks for taking the time to look into it. I'll just close it as invalid, maybe it was just a side-effect of something else. I'll be removing that code anyway in favor of RPX.

Comment: apparently not reproducible.

Comment: I have this issue. Ruby 1.9.2 on OSX.

Comment: This may help you - http://house9-code-samples.blogspot.com/2010/01/ruby-http-get.html

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.8 get seems to require a forward slash at the end of the uri.

> "http://www.google.com/"

worked, while

> "http://www.google.com"

did not.